# Throw a ZeroCheck exception object if the denominator is 0

Tags: c++, oop, templates, operator-overloading

I wrote this program which performs mathematical operations. And Well…, I tried to add a new header file “ZeroCheck.h” ..., and create (declare and define) an exception class ZeroCheck which displays the message "Denominator is 0, invalid division." via the what() member function. And I wanted to modify the main() function by creating Math3(6,0) object and using the try statement to output Mathematics objects. The ZeroCheck exception should be caught in catch block and the error message should be displayed if the division is invalid.
But unfortunately, the output is not exactly the same as what I expect, I mean when I run my program, the output is this:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "Mathematics.h"
#include "ZeroCheck.h"

// using std::cout, std::cerr, std::ostream;
using namespace std;


int
main()
{
    try {
        Mathematics<int> Math1(10, 5);
        Mathematics<double> Math2(5.5, 3.4);
        Mathematics<int> Math3(6, 0);

        cout << "Math 1:" << '\n';
        cout << Math1 << '\n' << '\n';

        cout << "Math 2:" << '\n';
        cout << Math2 << '\n';

        cout << "Math 3" << '\n';
        cout << Math3 << '\n';

    } catch (ZeroCheck e) {
        cerr << e.what() << '\n';
    }

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}


template <class T>
Mathematics<T>::Mathematics(T v1, T v2) : val1(v1), val2(v2) { }


template <class T>
T Mathematics<T>::addition()
{
    return (val1 + val2);
}


template <class T>
T Mathematics<T>::subtraction()
{
    return (val1 - val2);
}


template <class T>
T Mathematics<T>::multiplication()
{
    return (val1 * val2);
}


template <class T>
T Mathematics<T>::division()
{
    if (val2 == 0) {
        throw ZeroCheck("Denominator is 0, invalid division.");
    }

    return (val1 / val2);
}


template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Mathematics<T>& obj)
{
    os << "The result of calculation for: " << obj.val1 << " and " << obj.val2 << '\n'
       << "Sum is: " << obj.addition() << '\n'
       << "Difference is: " << obj.subtraction() << '\n'
       << "Product is: " << obj.multiplication() << '\n'
       << "Quotient is: " << obj.division() << '\n';

    return (os);
}
```

Mathematics.h

```
#ifndef MATHEMATICS_H_INCLUDED
#define MATHEMATICS_H_INCLUDED

#include <iostream>

using std::ostream;


template <class T>
class Mathematics {

    public:
        Mathematics(T, T);

        T addition();
        T subtraction();
        T multiplication();
        T division();

        template <class U>friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Mathematics<U>&);

    private:
        T val1;
        T val2;

};

#endif  /* MATHEMATICS_H_INCLUDED */
```

ZeroCheck.h

```
#ifndef ZEROCHECK_H_INCLUDED
#define ZEROCHECK_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>

using std::string;


class ZeroCheck {

    public:
        ZeroCheck()
        {
            this->msg = "";
        }


        ZeroCheck(string _msg)
        {
            this->msg = _msg;
        }

        string what()
        {
            return (msg);
        }

    private:
        string msg;
};

#endif  /* ZEROCHECK_H_INCLUDED */
```

But unfortunately, the output is not exactly the same as what I expect, I mean when I run my program, the output is this:

```
Math 1:                                                                                                                                         
The result of calculation for: 10 and 5   
Sum is: 15      
Difference is: 5  
Product is: 50                                  
Quotient is: 2                                                                                                                                  

      
Math 2:                               
The result of calculation for: 5.5 and 3.4
Sum is: 8.9     
Difference is: 2.1
Product is: 18.7                                
Quotient is: 1.61765                                                                                                                            

Math 3
The result of calculation for: 6 and 0
Sum is: 6
Difference is: 6
Product is: 0
// As you can see here the output is: 'Quotient is: Denominator is 0, invalid division.' Instead of just 'Denominator is 0, invalid division.'
Quotient is: Denominator is 0, invalid division.
```

This is the output that I expect:

```
Math 1:                                                                                                                                                                              
The result of calculation for: 10 and 5
Sum is: 15                                       
Difference is: 5
Product is: 50                                             
Quotient is: 2                            
                
                  
Math 2:            
The result of calculation for: 5.5 and 3.4
Sum is: 8.9       
Difference is: 2.1                               
Product is: 18.7
Quotient is: 1.61765


Math 3:            
The result of calculation for: 6 and 0
Sum is: 6
Difference is: 6                               
Product is: 0
Denominator is 0, invalid division.
```

Any idea what I can do to get the output I want? (Note: I have only tried to do what I could with the instructions provided, and by the way if you see something wrong with my code, I apologize in advance, I'm not familiar with some things yet, so...).

Comment: What did you observe, when running that code in your debugger?

Comment: Middle of one of your statements: `obj.multiplication() << '\n' << "Quotient is: " << obj.division()` Could you explain why you believe/expect the character `'\n'` should be part of the output, but the string literal `"Quotient is: "` should not? What part of the syntax justifies your expectation? (It looks like one continuous stream of characters to me.)

Comment: I seem to have overlooked something, I apologize and am sorry for asking such a s... question.

Comment: @TaurusSilver *"I seem to have overlooked something"* -- this is the reason I press people to explain their expectations. Sometimes writing out the reasons behind your expectations is enough to show you what you overlooked. Just force yourself to be detailed and not gloss over any details. Do this often enough, and you might get to the point where you catch your oversights earlier, without the aid of writing things out. ;)

Comment: @JaMiT I will, and I'll keep that in mind. Thanks you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Mathematics<T>& obj)
{
    os << "The result of calculation for: " << obj.val1 << " and " << obj.val2 << '\n'
    << "Sum is: " << obj.addition() << '\n'
    << "Difference is: " << obj.subtraction() << '\n'
    << "Product is: " << obj.multiplication() << '\n';
    if (obj.val1 == 0 || obj.val2 == 0)
    {
        os << obj.division() << '\n';
    }
    else
    {
        os << "Quotient is: " << obj.division() << '\n';
    }
    return (os);
}
```

You probably already figured out the answer to your question but I'd figured I'd share my response anyways. There might be a better way to check the condition but I think it looks good and it's easy to read! Good luck!!